# When was the Yemenite Jewish community isolated from the rest of the Jewish world?

Tags: jews, bible

The Yemenite Torah and Tanach is almost completely identical to that of the Jews in Europe, but there are a few minor spelling differences. When were the communities separated such that these spelling differences might have developed?

Answer (score 1):

[Jews settled in Yemen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yemenite_Jews) about 2500 years ago; their community was not isolated at first, but its isolation grew with time and reached its zenith about 2000 years ago with the destruction of the Second Temple and expulsion of the Jews from their Land.

I don't think anyone analyzed the accumulated scriptural differences the same way biologists study [Genetic drift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_drift).